# Base Image, Small Image, Thumbnail Image are not selected after product images csv import

Tags: product, import, image, csv

I have successfully imported product images using csv file but Base Image, Small Image and Thumbnail Image columns in Images tab, are not selected. No Image is selected by default. So products images are not displaying in front end.

Can someone please help in it, how they gets selected after product images csv imported

Answer (score 2):

What your CSV file format? Your CSV format should be following format.

[image]

Comment: Supravat, I took 4 columns sku, image, small_image and thumbnail. What are your rest 4 columns. Could you please explain

Comment: when you want to upload media image you must specify rest of columns. **_media_is_disabled** is use for unable the media caching system** & default media attribute id is 88 (**_media_attibute_id** ) , **_media_position** attribute set image positions, **_media_image** attribute save the  path of gallery images.

Comment: Thanks for this reply. Getting error _media_attibute_id is invalid. Set it to 88. What it should be? Also i want one image per product. No gallery images for product. Please suggest

Comment: can you give your csv format??

Comment: It working now. Thanks, somehow, I was doing something wrong

Comment: This question is useless if you give no details about what happened and how you overcame it

Answer (score 0):

The headers need to be base_image small_image thumbnail_image

Just writing thumbnail won't do anything